# How do I run "flutter clean" from the root of my flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In the beginning, I had an error that states: "Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform".

I'm running it on Android which is supported by flutter, so I made sure that I have the latest version of Flutter and Dart SDK installed. But the error was still there, this time I tried to run "flutter clean" but this error showed up: "No pubspec.yaml file found" and asked me to run it from the root of my project. Finally, I opened the command prompt and tried to navigate to the root directory, I'm not sure if it's right though: "C:\Users\phDRa\OneDrive\Desktop\Apotheke" but unfortunately, I had the same error.
I'm not sure if these steps are correct, but after that I was planning to run "flutter pub get", though I don't know where, and then I think the problem will be solved.

Comment: If your project is in file called `Apotheke` that means this is your project root

Comment: can you include a ss of your IDE that will show the `Explorer`(files tab)

Answer (score 0):

Root directory is the same address u used when you ran

```
Flutter create <project_name>
```

And the same address u use to open the vs code folder

So i think it will be easier if u just fun

```
Flutter clear
```

From the vs code terminal

Answer (score 0):

Its to simple.
open terminal in project directory and run this command
`flutter clean`.
the terminal could be CMD or power-Shell if you are on windows or
if you are on Linux or Mac you could use bash or zsh